# How to prove a surface is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a hyperboloid $M=(x^2+y^2-z^2=1)$

how do I prove it is orientable, I know that a surface is orientable is there exists a non zero 2 form on M or if there is a unit normal vector field on M, or even if M if compact or simply connected, but I don't know which one of these to choose, or how to go about actually proving this. Any help would be great!

Comment: Well, the Klein bottle is a compact surface not orientable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface is defined by an equation $g(x,y,z)=0$. The gradient of $g$ gives a field of normal vectors. They can be normalized to unit length.

More specifically, at the point $(x,y,z)$ on the hyperboloid, the vector
$$
\frac{(2x,2y,-2z)}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+4z^2}}=\frac{(x,y,-z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
$$
is normal to the surface and has unit length. (Note that neither the numerator nor the denominator is ever zero on the surface.)

Comment: Thank you, this is extremely helpful. Can I ask how you knew to choose this vector?

Comment: @user520403 I told you at the top of my answer: Write the defining equation as "$\text{something}=0$", and then take the gradient of the left-hand side.

Comment: so I have $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2-1=0$ but when I take the gradient isn't it just equal to (2x,2y,-2z)? how did you get the denominator?

Comment: @user520403 Indeed, the gradient is without any denominator. However, you wanted the normals to have unit length, right? That's what the denominator is for.